# I'm getting inconsistencies when running the following code in Pycharm

Tags: python, list, class, oop, valueerror

I'm writing a script for a deck of card in an OO way as shown below.

```
class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.card_list = self.build()

    def build(self):
        suit = ["S", "H", "D", "C"]
        val = ["ace", "two", "thr", "fou", "fiv", "six", "sev", "eig", "nin", "ten", "jac", "que", "kin"]
        return list(itertools.product(suit, val))

    def deal(self):
        cards = random.choices(population=self.card_list, k=3)
        [self.card_list.remove(i) for i in cards]
        return cards
```

My game has 4 players so I "deal" them like so:

```
deck = Deck()

player1.player_hand = deck.deal()
player2.player_hand = deck.deal()
player3.player_hand = deck.deal()
player4.player_hand = deck.deal()
```

But when I run this code, it's either running fine or giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sean/Desktop/Programming/Machine learning/All Foors AI/deck.py", line 73, in <module>
    player1.player_hand = deck.deal()
  File "C:/Users/Sean/Desktop/Programming/Machine learning/All Foors AI/deck.py", line 19, in deal
    [self.card_list.remove(i) for i in cards_3]
  File "C:/Users/Sean/Desktop/Programming/Machine learning/All Foors AI/deck.py", line 19, in <listcomp>
    [self.card_list.remove(i) for i in cards_3]
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Could some clarify for me why this is so?

Comment: that is not how to use list comprehensions, use a normal `for` loop but even then it makes little sense, if you want to use a list comprehension: `self.card_list = [card for card in self.card_list if card not in cards]` or better with a `for` loop: `for card in cards: self.card_list.remove(card)`, the error is pretty clear, you are trying to remove a card that has already been removed

Comment: I know not to use list comprehension, I didn't use it in my original script. I was messing around with my code to see if I could reduce the number of lines but the issue isn't that it gives an error, it's that sometimes it gives an error.

Comment: yes, that happens because you are removing a value that has already been removed because `choices` can return multiple identical values